# Configuring IIS for a session-less API environment

Tags: iis, coldfusion, iis-7.5, coldfusion-9

I have a fairly simple API environment running on an IIS site. The site is mostly configured with defaults and serving on average 4-6 request per second. All it does is take in information passed in through GET request parameters and stores it in a database.

As I said the site has an average load of 4-6 requests per second and right now crashes pretty often. I'm trying to reconfigure the site to handle more of a load, but I'm not hugely familiar with IIS configuration. Does anyone have advice on how to debug this issue or how to better configure IIS for a session-less API environment? I can confirm that the default logging doesn't give me any useful errors, but if desired I can post some here.

**Edit:**
This is the standard error I see in the Application Event Log in regards to the error

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17725, time stamp: 0x4ec4aa8e
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000c40f2
Faulting process id: 0xbc0
Faulting application start time: 0x01cddcf5147d18cc
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 5256ddd1-48e8-11e2-9c4a-0050560f015f
```

So far we have setup load balancing since the original post to help us out, but still see the error happening.

Comment: On the ColdFusion side of things, do you have an Application.cfc file?  If so, do you have session management set to false?

Comment: sessionManagement and clientManagement is off. setClientCookies and setDomainCookies is off as well.

Comment: I also set in the http response headers Pragma to no-cache; Cache-Control to no-cache; Expires to 2012-01-01.

Comment: What is crashing; IIS or ColdFusion?  You are asking about IIS configuration info so I assume the application pool is crashing.  If so, what event is being logged in the Window's System Log?

Comment: It is IIS crashing. I'll pull up the IIS logs in a moment.

Comment: If this is an IIS issue, you might get better help on [sf].

Comment: Expanding on Miguel-F's comment: You also need to check the ColdFusion logs. I would also check the status of jRun

Comment: ColdFusion and JRun don't complain about anything in all this. The logs have no errors happening.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/search?q=Faulting+application+name%3A+w3wp.exe